# Having trouble mocking an email server using JUnit

Tags: email, junit, mocking

I'm trying to mock sending an email (for the purposes of JUnit, v4.8.1, testing) and decided to use Dumbster, which I found through SO.  I'm using version 1.6.  I have this in my JUnit test …

```
    SimpleSmtpServer server = SimpleSmtpServer.start();
    boolean ret = m_emailSvc.sendEmail("me@me.com", 
                                       "you@you.com", 
                                       "localhost", 
                                       "Test", 
                                       "Test Body");
    Assert.assertTrue(ret);
    server.stop();
```

and I send an email this way …

```
public boolean sendEmail(final String toEmail,
                      final String fromEmail,
                      final String smtpHost,
                      final String subject,
                      final String body)
{

    boolean ret = true;
    // Get system properties
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();

    // Setup mail server
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);

    // Get the default Session object.
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

    try{
       // Create a default MimeMessage object.
       MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

       // Set From: header field of the header.
       message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail));

       // Set To: header field of the header.
       message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                new InternetAddress(toEmail));

       // Set Subject: header field
       message.setSubject(subject);

       // Now set the actual message
       message.setText(body);

       // Send message
       Transport.send(message);
    }catch (MessagingException mex) {
       ret = false;
       LOG.error(mex.getMessage(), mex);
    }   // try
    return ret;
}   // sendEmail
```

This fails with the exception below.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or is there an easier way to mock sending an email in a JUnit test?

```
java.net.BindException: Permission denied
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(PlainSocketImpl.java:521)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:414)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:326)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:192)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:104)
    at com.dumbster.smtp.SimpleSmtpServer.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
[ERROR]: org.mainco.subco.email.service.EmailServiceImpl - Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
```

nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1934)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
        at org.mainco.subco.email.service.EmailServiceImpl.sendEmail(EmailServiceImpl.java:62)
        at org.mainco.subco.email.service.EmailServiceTest.testSendEmail(EmailServiceTest.java:23)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:382)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:241)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:228)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:384)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:527)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:476)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:288)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:231)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1900)

Comment: Is your dumbster running ? You're getting Connection Refused on localhost port 25 indicating dumbster has not been started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to mock the static call from the Transport class instead, using PowerMock (v.1.5.1).

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class EmailServiceTest
{

@Autowired
private EmailService m_emailSvc = new EmailServiceImpl();

@Test
@PrepareForTest( Transport.class )
public final void testSendEmail()
{
    suppress(methodsDeclaredIn(Transport.class));
    boolean ret = m_emailSvc.sendEmail("me@me.com",
                                       "you@you.com", 
                                       "localhost",
                                       "Test",
                                       "Test Body");
    Assert.assertTrue(ret);
}   // testSendEmail
```

Answer (score 0):

What about wrapping the call to `Transport` is a mockable object? Inject the mock and verify the call.

What I mean is something like this...

```
class MyTransport{
    public void send(MimeMessage message){
        Transport.send(message);
    }
}
```

Then inject an instance of this class into your class above. In your production env you have the same code. However, when doing testing you could pass in a Mock for `MyTransport` and thereby verify the call to `send` without the need of a server.

Comment: Transport is static, as you can tell.  Are you saying convert it to a member field, write some setter code and then inject the mock that way?